# KeyError when merging DataFrames in pandas

Tags: pandas, machine-learning

I'm trying to merge two DataFrames in pandas using the merge() function, but I'm getting a KeyError with the column name. Here's my code:

```
draft_history_player_info_df = pd.merge(draft_history_player_info_df, games_played, left_on='person_id', right_on='player_id', how='left')
```

The draft_history_player_info_df DataFrame has a column named 'person_id', and I want to merge it with the games_played DataFrame using the 'player_id' column. However, I'm getting a KeyError: 'player_id' even though I have verified that the column exists in games_played. What could be causing this issue?

i tried that and got this result

```
KeyError: 'player_id'
```

Comment: Make sure there are no spaces (at the beginning or end) in your column names. Rename the columns if you have to. The likely error is that the key really doesn't exist (even though  you think it does). Troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Another issue might be that the player_id is not a column but the `index` of the right dataframe. You need to provide sample data that reproduces the problem, really. We can only guess.